# Why are Boolean and DateTime Literals Wrong in NHibernate SQL Logging?

Tags: nhibernate

I use log4net to log *NHibernate.SQL* at the **Debug** level.
I use the `MsSql2012Dialect` dialect against the latest Sql Server database.
The logged SQL is s bit different from the SQL that gets sent to the DB.  Notably, for bit fields that are mapped a `Boolean`, NH produces values of *1* and *0*, but the logging output uses *True* and *False*.
Also, today's DateTime gets sent to the DB as *'2023-06-16 08:32:09.9586347'* but gets logged as *2023-06-16T08:32:09.9586347Z* (different format, *sans* quotes).
This is inconvenient because I can't simply paste a query from the log into a database client and run it; I first have to replace the Boolean and DateTime literals so that it will run.

Can someone explain why this is happening and/or suggest a solution?

PS:  I've written a log4net `PatternLayout` that gets rid of the parameters (as in @p1, @p2) and puts their values inline, making the SQL more readable.  I'm happy to share it if anyone's interested.